# while trying to check prime number i ended with this error

Tags: solidity

```js
    contract PrimeNumberChecker {

     function isPrime(uint n) public pure returns(string memory){
        for(uint i = 2;i<n;i++){
             if(n % i ==0){
                return "Not a prime";
               }
             else{
                return "prime";
            }
          }
      }
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

The code you have mentioned will always return in the first loop itself. The `return prime` statement should be outside the loop. This is the correct implementation.

```js
contract PrimeNumberChecker {
    function isPrime(uint256 n) public pure returns (string memory) {
        for (uint256 i = 2; i < n; i++) {
            if (n % i == 0) {
                return "Not a prime";
            }
        }
        return "prime";
    }
}
```